# Split strings by white spaces in C#

Tags: c#, regex, split

I want to split a string by white spaces except if the text inside the string is in *double quotes* ("text") or *single quotes* ('text').

I am doing it with this function:

```
public static string[] ParseKeywordExpression(string keywordExpressionValue, bool isUniqueKeywordReq)
{
    keywordExpressionValue = keywordExpressionValue.Trim();
    if (keywordExpressionValue == null || !(keywordExpressionValue.Length > 0))
        return new string[0];
    int idx = keywordExpressionValue.Trim().IndexOf(" ");
    if (idx == -1)
        return new string[] { keywordExpressionValue };
    //idx = idx + 1;
    int count = keywordExpressionValue.Length;
    ArrayList extractedList = new ArrayList();
    while (count > 0)
    {
        if (keywordExpressionValue[0] == '"')
        {
            int temp = keywordExpressionValue.IndexOf(BACKSLASH, 1, keywordExpressionValue.Length - 1);
            while (keywordExpressionValue[temp - 1] == '\\')
            {
                temp = keywordExpressionValue.IndexOf(BACKSLASH, temp + 1, keywordExpressionValue.Length - temp - 1);
            }
            idx = temp + 1;
        }
        if (keywordExpressionValue[0] == '\'')
        {
            int temp = keywordExpressionValue.IndexOf(BACKSHASH_QUOTE, 1, keywordExpressionValue.Length - 1);
            while (keywordExpressionValue[temp - 1] == '\\')
            {
                temp = keywordExpressionValue.IndexOf(BACKSHASH_QUOTE, temp + 1, keywordExpressionValue.Length - temp - 1);
            }
            idx = temp + 1;
        }
        string s = keywordExpressionValue.Substring(0, idx);
        int left = count - idx;
        keywordExpressionValue = keywordExpressionValue.Substring(idx, left).Trim();
        if (isUniqueKeywordReq)                    
        {
            if (!extractedList.Contains(s.Trim('"')))
            {
                extractedList.Add(s.Trim('"'));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            extractedList.Add(s.Trim('"'));
        }
        count = keywordExpressionValue.Length;
        idx = keywordExpressionValue.IndexOf(SPACE);
        if (idx == -1)
        {
            string add = keywordExpressionValue.Trim('"', ' ');
            if (add.Length > 0)
            {
                if (isUniqueKeywordReq )
                {
                    if (!extractedList.Contains(add))
                    {
                        extractedList.Add(add);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    extractedList.Add(add);
                }
            }                   
            break;
        }
    }
    return (string[])extractedList.ToArray(typeof(string));
}
```

Is there any other way to do it or can this function can be optimised?

For example, I wish to split the string

> %ABC% %aasdf% aalasdjjfas "c:\Document and Setting\Program Files\abc.exe"

to

> %ABC%
>   %aasdf%
>   aalasdjjfas
>   "c:\Document and Setting\Program Files\abc.exe"

Comment: So find a CSV regex and accommodate it to use `\s` instead of a comma?

Comment: @BradChristie i have edited my quiestion on how i wish the output. I dont thinl CSV REGEX would help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The very simplest regex for this, handling single and double quotes:

`("((\\")|([^"]))*")|('((\\')|([^']))*')|(\S+)`

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(""((\\"")|([^""]))*"")|('((\\')|([^']))*')|(\S+)");
var matches = regex.Matches(inputstring);
foreach (Match match in matches) {
    extractedList.Add(match.Value);
}
```

So basically four to five lines of code is enough.

The expression, explained:

```
Main structure:
("((\\")|([^"]))*")    Double-quoted token
|                      , or
('((\\')|([^']))*')    single-quoted token
|                      , or
(\S+)                  any group of non-space characters

Double-quoted token:
(                      Group starts
    "                  Initial double-quote
    (                  Inner group starts
        (\\")          Either a backslash followed by a double-quote
        |              , or  
        ([^"])         any non-double-quote character
    )*                 The inner group repeats any number of times (or zero)
    "                  Ending double-quote
)

Single-quoted token:
(                      Group starts
    '                  Initial single-quote
    (                  Inner group starts
        (\\')          Either a backslash followed by a single-quote
        |              , or  
        ([^'])         any non-single-quote character
    )*                 The inner group repeats any number of times (or zero)
    '                  Ending single-quote
)

Non-space characters:
(                      Group starts
    \S                 Non-white-space character
    +                  , repeated at least once
)                      Group ends
```

Comment: Yes its working on double quotes but not on SINGLE QUOTES ex- %ABC% %aasdf% aalasdjjfas "c:\Doctment and Setting\Program Files\abc.exe" 'c:\Doctment and Setting\Program Files\abc.exe'

Comment: Updated my answer to also include single quotes.

Comment: Very nice, especially the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like RegEx, this method should be able to split quoted strings, and ignores consecutive spaces:

```
public IEnumerable<string> SplitString(string input)
{
    var isInDoubleQuote = false;
    var isInSingleQuote = false;
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var c in input)
    {
        if (!isInDoubleQuote && c == '"')
        {
            isInDoubleQuote = true;
            sb.Append(c);
        }
        else if (isInDoubleQuote)
        {
            sb.Append(c);
            if (c != '"')
                continue;
            if (sb.Length > 2)
                yield return sb.ToString();
            sb = sb.Clear();
            isInDoubleQuote = false;
        }
        else if (!isInSingleQuote && c == '\'')
        {
            isInSingleQuote = true;
            sb.Append(c);
        }
        else if (isInSingleQuote)
        {
            sb.Append(c);
            if (c != '\'')
                continue;
            if (sb.Length > 2)
                yield return sb.ToString();
            sb = sb.Clear();
            isInSingleQuote = false;
        }
        else if (c == ' ')
        {
            if (sb.Length == 0)
                continue;
            yield return sb.ToString();
            sb.Clear();
        }
        else
            sb.Append(c);
    }
    if (sb.Length > 0)
        yield return sb.ToString();
}
```

*Edit: Changed return type to IEnumerable, using yield and StringBuilder*

Comment: That will produce a rather lot of GC'able temporary strings, won't it?

Comment: If you aren't going to hit the results more than once, but will just `foreach` through them, then changing the return type to `IEumerable<string>` and replacing the `output.Add` calls with `yield return curentString;` is a good idea. It's also a case where using `StringBuilder` rather than lots of concatenations makes sense.

Comment: I completely agree, @JonHanna. `yield return` is an under-used feature of C#. The `StringBuilder` argument is valid, but since it's probably only used for parsing a command line argument sequence, the performance hit isn't huge. But nevertheless, there's no excuse for sloppy code.

Comment: @JonHanna `yeild return` what does it exactly do... sorry i dont know much of these performance related stuff

Comment: @adcool2007 Try it and see. `yield return` returns the result to the code that is `foreach`ing through it, and then continues to the next bit of work. What really happens is the code is compiled into a method that returns a hidden anonymous class that implements `IEnumerable<string>` with your method being used to create the constructor, `Current`, `Dispose` (if you had a `using` block in your code) and most of all `MoveNext`...

Comment: A great demonstration is `static IEnumerable<int> TestYield(){yield return 1; yield return 2; yield return 3;}public static Main(string[] args){foreach(int x in TestYield())Console.WriteLine(x);}` The issue here is not so much about performance - in some cases your code is slightly more efficient (if you were going to need other members of `List<string>` and hence put it in a list anyway) and you can usually get slightly more performance by hand-coding the equivalent class to that which `yield return` results in. Rather than pure performance it's a matter of habits that produce a result that..

Comment: is needed, without filling a collection object that won't be used any more after you've `foreach`ed through it. Sure it is a performance issue when the collection is huge, but mostly its something that'll become the natural way for you once you're used to it. You won't have to optimise for the few cases where it really matters, because you'll just have done it that way. `StringBuilder` is more a performance-pure matter, it does nothing you can't do with strings and `+=`, but after around 5 `+` or `+=` `StringBuilder` becomes the way to go. This is often overstated, a good habit is to use it...

Comment: when you see a lot of concatenations happening. Using it in other cases (or perhaps even going back to `+=` in rare cases) is an optimisation, but being in the habit of using `StringBuilder` for this sort of work you'll have reduced the number of times you need to move from "natural" to "optimised". (An example of a pure optimisation is if you yield returned the `StringBuilder` rather than the `string` - in **some** cases this would be more efficient still, but it introduces a way for the calling code to mess things up - hence a bad habit we might do in an urgent case, rather than a good habit

Comment: @JonHanna btw which is more performance oriented Regex or C# code in similar operations??

Comment: Edited answer with the suggested changes

Comment: It depends. In this case I'd bet on the C#, but while it should almost always be possible to build a C# equivalent to a regex that beats it, often this would involve building a very complicated state-machine in C# that the regex encodes in a few characters. In terms of good habits, I'd say you should go for whichever solution seems to offer the most immediately obvious fix. I'd only worry about which was more performant if it proved a bottleneck or if it was part of a library where I couldn't know it wouldn't be some calling code's bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

I escape the single and double quotes by using the hex values of `\x27` and `\x22` in the string. It makes the C# literal text of the pattern easier to read and manipulate.

Also the use of `IgnorePatternWhitespace` is being done for it allows one ot comment the pattern for better readability; does not affect regex processing.

```
string data = @"'single' %ABC% %aasdf% aalasdjjfas ""c:\Document and Setting\Program Files\abc.exe""";

string pattern = @"(?xm)     # Tell the regex compiler we are commenting (x = IgnorePatternWhitespace)
                             # and tell the compiler this is multiline (m),
                             # In Multiline the ^ matches each start line and $ is each EOL
                             # -Pattern Start-
^(                           # Start at the beginning of the line always
 (?![\r\n]|$)                # Stop the match if EOL or EOF found.
 (?([\x27\x22])              # Regex If to check for single/double quotes
      (?:[\x27\x22])         # \\x27\\x22 are single/double quotes
      (?<Token>[^\x27\x22]+) # Match this in the quotes and place in Named match Token
      (?:[\x27\x22])

  |                          # or (else) part of If when Not within quotes

     (?<Token>[^\s\r\n]+)    # Not within quotes, but put it in the Token match group
  )                          # End of Pattern OR

(?:\s?)                       # Either a space or EOL/EOF
)+                            # 1 or more tokens of data.
";

Console.WriteLine( string.Join(" | ", 

Regex.Match(data, pattern)
        .Groups["Token"]
        .Captures
        .OfType<Capture>()
        .Select( cp => cp.Value )
                )
                );
/* Output
single | %ABC% | %aasdf% | aalasdjjfas | c:\Document and Setting\Program Files\abc.exe
 */
```

The above is based on the following two blog entries I've written:

- [C# Extracting CSV data into Linq and a Dictionary using Regular Expressions](http://omegacoder.com/?p=542)
- [Regular Expressions and the If Conditional](http://omegacoder.com/?p=56)

Comment: I am glad you found your answer. I am a strong believer in regex and if people would take the time to learn it, its a powerful tool which regardless of language (C#/Java/php) one can use it to the same effect throughout. :-)